# How do I add pure JavaScript Filter/Search (ul, li) List to Ionic Cordova App?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic Framwork and Cordova, and trying to add Filter/Search List functionality to a simple App (HTML shown below is served from the server side and accessed by the app). I have added the following pure JavaScript into the 'head' section of my index.html but it does not work in the App. What is the correct way to add it to Ionic App?

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput-A1');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myList-A1");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
  //li = ul.querySelectorAll("list-group-item");

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput-A1" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search item..">
<div>

<div>
<ul class="list-group" id="myList-A1">
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google </a></li>
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">YouTube</a></li>
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank">Microsoft</a></li>
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

P.S. I am using Ionic-v3

Answer (score 0):

It seems pure JavaScript works just fine. I have added it to HTML which also contains the ul, li list on server side. Sorry for this trouble.